# I have a multidimensional array, and need to sort it by a "column" but keeping the other column organized

Tags: php, arrays

my array have this structure:

```
$news = array('id' => '', 'views' => '');
```

i need to order this by the most viewed, but it have to match the id. I've done some research but got many doubts.

Comment: are the id and views properties arrays that associate with one another by index?

Comment: yes, they're are associated by the index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having some trouble deciphering exactly what you mean with the question but here a couple of thinks that may work for you.

if your array is composed like

```
array(
      array("id"=>1, "views"=>50),
      array("id"=>3, "views"=>16)
);
```

Then you can use usort with a closure(php 5.3)

```
usort($news, function ($a, $b){ return $a["views"] - $b["views"]});
```

if you want it in descending order you can  just swap the $a and $b in the closure

```
usort($news, function ($a, $b){ return $b["views"] - $a["views"]});
```

If you have an array that is composed like

```
array(
     "id"=>array(1,2),
     "views"=>array(50, 16)
);
```

Then you can use [array_multisort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)

```
array_multisort($news["views"], $news["id"]);
```

or if you want it in descending order

```
array_multisort($news["views"], SORT_DESC, SORT_NUMERIC, $news["id"]);
```

**UPDATE**

The final solution.. news was an object with a views and id array properties.  The final solution was:

```
array_multisort($news->views, $news->id);
```

Comment: it returns: usort() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given

Comment: i have the first case, but it returns the error "usort() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given". And i'm sorry for my confuse question, thats because i'm not a native english speaker :/

Comment: news isn't an array then... you might be able to cast it to one by using `(array)$news`

Comment: another error, it says "undefined index views". The print_r of the array return this structure (and thanks for being patient):

Array
(
    [id] => Array
        (
            [0] => 283
            [1] => 284
            [2] => 305
 
        )

    [views] => Array
        (
            [0] => 73
            [1] => 37255
            [2] => 219827
        )
)

Comment: try this `array_multisort($news->views, $news->id);`

Comment: It worked!!!!!! Thank you very much :D (now i realize how dumb i've been hahaha)